# Write data in PList with PropertyListEncoder / PropertyListSerialization Swift

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I'm currently trying to store some Data (two Doubles) in .plist file.

I've set reading from it whith next code:

```
func fetchDataFromPlist() {
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Data", ofType: "plist") {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
            WeatherModel.dict = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: [], format: nil) as! [String:Double]
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to understand - how can i write Data in same .plist file?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You can't. An app's bundle is read-only. The file needs to be written in an appropriate folder within your app's sandbox.

Comment: Do you mean - .plist in this case are read-only?

Comment: Any file in the app bundle is read-only.

Comment: Okay, get it.

Thanks alot! :)